# AWS SES how to deliberately delay sending an email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is there an option in AWS to deliberately **delay sending an email**?
I mean is it possible to tell AWS to send this email after 5 or 10 or 30 minutes when we call the AmazonSimpleEmailService library?

Comment: An SQS delay queue would be an ideal solution, but that unfortunately only allows a maximum delay of 15 minutes. I think you can do longer delays through AmazonMQ/ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ideally NO !!!

> Amazon SES attempts to deliver emails to the Internet within a few seconds of each request.

code in lambda can be delayed using any of the time based libraries but the problem is when to invoke lambda or what will invoke lambda.For this
, you can use sqs with lambda.

- send the request to sqs queue
- you will know when request has come. this will act as a
- execute lambda after your desire time

source [faq](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/)